# Output text at the very end of custom Nx workspace generator

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl, angular-schematics

Is it possible to output/log text at the very end the workspace generator output?
I would like to notify the user of the next steps he/she should do, but my logs are kind of hidden above all the output generated by the `tree` updates.

```
export default async function (tree: Tree, schema: GeneratorOptions) {

  await applicationGenerator(tree, {
   // options go here
  });

  //format all the new files
  await formatFiles(tree);

  // log out next steps
  logger.info('next steps');
  logger.info('* Complete information in /src/environment files');
  logger.info('* Adjust example routes in /src/app/app.tsx');
}
```

The code above results in the following output, as you can see my logs are completely at the top (and nobody would ever see them)

[image: output workspace generator]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and judging from [this open issue](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/7332) it does not seem to be a way to do it.

What I ended up doing was wrapping the command to run the generator in a node script and then run that script instead:

```
import {execSync} from "child_process";
execSync('nx workspace-generator your-generator', {stdio: 'inherit'})
console.log('after')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to print a custom message by returning an anonymous callback and just console.log or whatever you want to do in it.

```
export default async function (tree: Tree, schema: GeneratorOptions) {
    await applicationGenerator(tree, {
        // options go here
    });
    
    //format all the new files
    await formatFiles(tree);
    
    return () => {
        console.log('The end')
    };
}
```